# Python Kivy Use colored emoji in Label

Tags: python, kivy, emoji

I've been trying to display colored emojis using Python & Kivy but the best I can achieve is this:

[image: emoji in kivy]

I tried using different fonts but none of them display with color. I also tried `otf` file formats with no success. Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="️", font_name="seguiemj")

TestApp().run()
```

I'm not trying to change the text color but actually display the fonts with their built in colors. I've tried searching myself but there doesn't seem to be a definitive yes or no to whether this is even possible.

It would greatly help if anyone can tell me how to accomplish this in the case that it is possible and an alternative method if it is not (hopefully one that doesn't involve using images).

Comment: Try just adding `color=(1, 0, 0, 1)` to your `Label`.

Comment: That will just turn everything red. Some of these emojis have multiple colors so I want to use the color built into the emojis

Answer (score 0):

try using kivymd maybe it can solve the problem

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.MDlabel import MDLabel

class TestApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text="️", font_name="seguiemj")

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).